# including android library not working for ant inside eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, adt

I have 2 `Android` library projects. *LibraryA* and *LibraryB*.

I have a project called *project1* which needs to reference classes and stuff that are in *LibraryA* and *LibraryB*.

I am using the auto generated `Ant` script inside `eclipse` to build all the projects. Note: that i have removed all other builders from each of the projects and only using the `Ant` builder.

When i run the build script for *project1* with the following targets "clean,debug", `eclipse's` console says `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`. **HOWEVER**, if i look at the code inside eclipse there are lots of error lines and x's in the code saying that the `imports cannot be resolved` and numerous other errors. Basically it is telling me the references to the library projects is not there. It is also telling me the `R's` cannot be resolved either.

**I thought ADT17 was going to fix this issue but it still persists. Am i doing something wrong? How can i solve this issue, so that eclipse allows the references and everything builds fine?**

Running the application on the phone is working.

---

```
# The project.properties file for project1
target=android-10
android.library.reference.1=../LibraryA
android.library.reference.2=../LibraryB
```

---

I have a dirty fix that solves this problem, but i would like a much cleaner solution that is automatic and does not require editing the auto generated build.xml that android generates. It seems like this type of thing should be working out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. `gen` was not included as a `src` folder for the project. Once i included `gen` as a source folder all the `R` references started working.

**I do NOT have the jars in my `libs` folder for the project.**

My "dirty solution" i mentioned earlier is adding a `post-compile` target and taking the `classes.jar` that is generated during build and renaming it to `"TheProjectName".jar` and then the project will see the jar file references.

The "dirty solution" is what i was doing pre-ADT17 and was hoping to avoid in ADT17, but it seems like this issue is still not resovled. If anyone has any suggestions on how to fix that problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to place your jar libraries into `libs` folder?
In adt17 your jars must be placed into it.

Comment: Tried including the generated `jar` of each library in the `libs` of *project1* and my `R` references are still red and with 'x'. But it still builds successfully. I also do not see why i need to include those in the `libs` directory when i am teling `android` i want those libraries included as library projects. If they need to be in the `libs` directory, why not place them there for me automatically. That seems silly to write a custom target inside their auto generated build script that does that...

Comment: This did solve the issue of most the references being red, except the `R` references.

Answer (score 0):

Either make an Android project through Eclipse or type "android create project" to the console (and don't forget the additional params like -n, -t and maybe others). If you've already created Android project with Eclipse but are missing the build.xml file (and possibly others) run "android update project -p ." in the root folder of your project to update it and add the missing files. If you create an Android project through Eclipse or commandline, folders like "gen" (and others) should be properly set up.